# Acceleration in musical tempo

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Having an initial tempo in a musical phrase (say 60 notes per minute) and the whole duration of the phrase (say the phrase lasts for 4 seconds and consists of 8 notes) is it possible to calculate an acceleration in the velocity of these 8 notes (knowing that an acceleration is happening) without knowing the final velocity?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference in time between the notes (period of the repeated pattern) as the phrase continues. If you were to think of the notes as a repeated pattern, then the frequency of the notes (notes per second) could be found by taking $\frac{1}{period}$. This would be in notes per second, you could easily convert to notes per minute.

You could then plot the frequency against time to effectively plot a velocity time graph, and then use the gradient to find the effective acceleration of the increase in tempo (the increase in the number of notes per minute, per second).

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the velocity of the notes but this is what I understood from the question, I hope it helps.

Comment: How could i find the difference of the notes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the difference'?

Comment: You said i could find the difference in time btwn. the notes. How can i calculate the difference in  time btwn the notes if i don't know with which factor they are getting faster or slower?

Comment: Use a stopwatch